# How to change behaviour of `check_overlap = TRUE`?

Tags: r, ggplot2

My data is structured as follows:

```
> Comparison
# A tibble: 12 x 3
   round TotalShots  Year
   <int>         <dbl> <dbl>
 1     1            70  2021
 2     2            68  2021
 3     3            76  2021
 4     4            73  2021
 5     5            66  2021
 6     6            70  2021
 7     1           115  2020
 8     2           106  2020
 9     3            75  2020
10     4            73  2020
11     5            82  2020
12     6            84  2020
```

I can plot this in `ggplot2` via:

```
ggplot(Comparison, aes(x = round, y = TotalShots, 
                         colour = factor(Year), label = TotalShots)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point(size = 14) +
  geom_text(colour = "black", size = 5, check_overlap = TRUE)
```

However, in the plot, I have the label, at Rd3 printing as 76 and not 75. I assume this is because of `check_overlap = TRUE` however the plot is wrong, as year = 2020 for round = 3 should have the label of 75 and not 76.

Is there any way to please fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `ggrepel` library for clarity of labels and to  avoid overlapping.

```
library(ggrepel)
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(Comparison, aes(x = round, y = TotalShots, 
                       colour = factor(Year), label = TotalShots)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point(size = 14) +
  geom_label_repel(colour = "black", size = 5, nudge_y = 0.8)
```

[image]